# Magento 2 : get second level categories of parent category except default category by using block?

Tags: magento2, backend, php-5.6

Like we have Women category

```
1.Women
 1.1 Tops
 1.2.Bottoms
```

I want to display Women and 2nd level of that category.

which libraries used to get subcategory?

**My requirement is :** [image]

Comment: please look this, if it can help you.
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/navigation-top.html

Comment: Thank you for the help but i want to display topcategories and their subcategories on homepage

Comment: you can see 
https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1813

Comment: Where do you want to show this? On top menu or left navigation?

Comment: I dont want on navigation . please refer updated requirement and any help is appreciated

Comment: I achieved my requirement by following code. any suggestions are appreciated.

Step 1: following code is added in display block:
 protected $_categoryRepository; and used  \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository in public function __construct
public function getSubCategories($parentcatid){
     $parentcategories = $this->_categoryRepository->get($parentcatid);
  $subcategories = $parentcategories->getChildrenCategories();
  return $subcategories;
    }

Comment: Step 2 : added code in my view file
$subcategories = $block->getSubCategories(21);
    foreach ($subcategories as $sub) {
     echo $sub->getName(). "<br><hr>";
    }

Answer (score 1):

Magento2 got Second level category by collection,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create();   
$categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');     
$categories->addAttributeToFilter('level' , 2); 
$secondlevelcategory = $categories->getColumnValues('entity_id');
```